# Polling a Google Contacts change using an apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I need to detect change in my contacts book, unfortunately People API provides no such feature.  I have read in some blogs polling is needed. I dont find any API to poll https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/reference Can anyone suggest me how can this feature be achieved?

Comment: Currently this feature is not available in the current version of the Contacts API yet. You may want to request this particular feature using the instructions in this link: [Submit ideas for Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762?hl=en)

Comment: What kind of changes are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sort of function to receive and email if either the number of your contacts or the number of your contact emails change.

```
function sendEmailIfContactChange() {
  const gObj = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  const contacts=ContactsApp.getContacts();
  var n=0;
  contacts.forEach((c)=>{c.getEmails().forEach((e)=>{n++;});});
  if(!gObj.hasOwnProperty('contacts')) {
    gObj.contacts=contacts.length;
    gObj.emails=n;
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties(gObj);
    return;
  } else {
    let pc = gObj.contacts;
    let pe = gObj.emails;
    gObj.contacts = contacts.length;
    gObj.emails = n;
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperties(gObj);
    if(pc != contacts.length || pe != n) {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(gobj.globals.privateemail,'Contacts Have Change',`Old Contact: ${pc} New Contacts: ${contacts.length} \nOld Emails: ${pe} New Emails: ${n}`);
    }
  } 
}
```

And you can create polling trigger like this:

```
function createPollingTrigger() {
  const ts = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().map(t=>t.getHandlerFunction());
  if(!~ts.indexOf('sendEmaiIfContactChange')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailIfContactChange').timeBased().everyHours(2).create();
  }
}
```